# Remove wrapping div from field type radios (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying my hand at theming form output and am stuck on radios. I am attempting to remove the div that wraps a set of radios,

```
div.form-item > div.form-radios > div.form-type-radio > input[type="radio"]+label
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- Remove that
```

I have a sample form:

```
function no_name_form($form, &$form_submit) {
    $form['radios'] = array(
        '#type'    => 'radios',
        '#title'   =>'Question text',
        '#options' => array(
            '1' => t('yes'),
            '0' => t('no')
        ),
        '#theme'   => 'no_name_radios',
    );
    return $form;
}
```

and I register the theme functions for both the radios group and individual radio buttons:

```
function no_name_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'no_name_radios' => array(
            'arguments' => array('element' => NULL),
        ),
        'no_name_radio' => array(
            'arguments' => array('element' => NULL),
        ),
    );
}
```

Then I define the theme functions:

```
function theme_no_name_radios($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $attributes = array();
    if (isset($element['#id'])) {
        $attributes['id'] = $element['#id'];
    }
    $attributes['class'] = 'form-radios test';
    if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
        $attributes['class'] .= ' ' . implode(' ', $element['#attributes']['class']);
    }
    if (isset($element['#attributes']['title'])) {
        $attributes['title'] = $element['#attributes']['title'];
    }
    return '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . (!empty($element['#children']) ? $element['#children'] : '') . '</div>';
}

function theme_no_name_radio($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'radio';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name','#return_value' => 'value'));

  if (isset($element['#return_value']) && $element['#value'] !== FALSE && $element['#value'] == $element['#return_value']) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));

  return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

When I use even the stock code from Drupal 7 to build the theme functions, the radios come out blank, and at this point none of the code has changed.

Ultimately, I want to end up with this:

```
div.form-item div.form-type-radio > input[type="radio"]+label
```

I am not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: All of the methodology I used came from: http://www.encodez.com/blog/how-to-theme-radio-drupal.html

Comment: Hi @Rob, the above post has been moved to new domain. The updated URL is here https://uppercase.dev/blog/how-to-theme-radios-in-drupal

Answer (score 2):

The `div.form-radios` is set by the theme wrapper of the radios. Use this code to prevent the theme wrapper from adding the additional div:

```
function no_name_form($form, &$form_submit) {
  $form['radios'] = array(
    '#type'    => 'radios',
    '#title'   =>'Question text',
    '#options' => array(
        '1' => t('yes'),
        '0' => t('no')
    ),
    '#theme'   => 'no_name_radios',
    '#theme_wrappers' => array(),
  );
  return $form;
}
```